# Windows: Test if entry is a file or a folder

Tags: windows

I Have to create 5 subfolders under every folder in a folder. This rootfolder contains files as well as folders. In this rootfolder are subfolders for our relations and we need to create 5 subfolders in every relation-folders.

I have been playing with:
for %%i in (*.*) do echo %%i
but this only shows files

when I do it like this:
for %%i in (*.) do echo %%i
it shows nothing

When, from a command-prompt, I do: 
DIR *.
it shows the subfolders. But I need to get this working in a batchfile

Any ideas?

Adrie de Regt

Answer (score 0):

The following command will enumerate all folders and subfolders:

```
for /d /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
```

### References

- [for - Command syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)
- [for /d](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)